# C# -Fetch Node Value and corresponding count for XML elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML in below format. This XML is assigned to an XDocument object.

```
<root>
<event>
<command>A1</command>
</event>
<event>
<command>B1</command>
</event>
<event>
<command>A1</command>
</event>
<event>
<command>C1</command>
</event>
</root>
```

I need to fetch the Node Value for all `<command>` nodes and the number of times each of them occur. In the above case, my desired output would be

```
A1 2
B1 1
C1 1
```

I also need the above results to go into object as below

```
var cmdList=from appinfo in doc.Root.Elements()
                    select new
                    {
                     Cname= ...
                     CCount =...
                     }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534304%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):-

```
var result = xdoc.Descendants("event")
                 .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)x.Element("command")))
                 .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("command"))
                 .Select(x => new
                             {
                                Value = x.Key,
                                Count = x.Count()
                             });
```

Comment: Yes, this is just what I wanted! only slight improvement. How can i get rid of nulls. One of the x.Key value is null. Where should my where clause go

Comment: @mhn - Just filter it before grouping, check my update.